# Integrating Django And Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use twitter bootstrap with django applications I'm about to develop and I wonder what is the best way to do it - should I do it 'regullarly' , i.e implementing the python code in the twitter bootstrap template, or whether there is any django package which integrates between django and twitter bootsrap ?

Answer (score 3):

Django is server-side. Twitter-Bootstrap is client-side. There's no clash and no need for special tools to integrate. I use both on a daily basis with no problem at all

Answer (score 2):

There are many packages integrating them: https://www.djangopackages.com/search/?q=bootstrap

Personally I don't really understand your question though, Django takes care of html rendering and python code, twitter bootstrap does css. Since you write your own templates I assume, you can integrate them when you write the templates.

Answer (score 1):

I think its best practice to keep your template clean. There is no harm doing custom styling. 
Anyway, you can check this git responsibility though [Django Bootstrap toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this couple pretty often so I extracted repeated patterns into the simple project skeleton: [faststart-bootstrap](https://bitbucket.org/aselivanov/faststart-bootstrap). It's Django with Bootstrap 3 support.

Answer (score 0):

[django-awesome-bootstrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-awesome-bootstrap/) on Pypi add functionality in django projects for twitter bootstrap and font awesome and makes it easy to integrate into your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Much to late to this party, but since this question did pop up on Google, I'd add that for Bootstrap3 you would use https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3. Disclaimer: I'm the author.